# How to get the amount of x movement for my sprite since the last frame?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a sprite that moves and I'm looking for a method to get the amount of x movement since the last frame. So that the new position is updated and that the x movement amount for the next frame is available. Anyone know how I can do this?

I know I can write:

```
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {

    print(player.position.x)

}
```

To get the current x position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a variable to your class called e.g. `var lastPlayerPosition: CGPoint?`

In the update block, get the players current position, compare it to the lastPlayerPosition and then update the lastPlayerPosition.

Then compare the CGPoints to get the distance moved.

```
var xDistance: CGFloat = 0.0
var distance: CGFloat = 0.0
var lastPlayerPosition: CGPoint?

override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {

    if self.lastPlayerPosition == nil {
        self.lastPlayerPosition = player.position
        return
    }

    xDistance = fabs(Float(self.lastPlayerPosition.x) - Float(player.position.x))
    distance = hypotf(Float(self.lastPlayerPosition.x) - Float(player.position.x), 
                      Float(self.lastPlayerPosition.y) - Float(player.position.y)) 

    print("lastPosition.x: \(self.lastPlayerPosition?.x) | player.position.x: \(player.position.x)")        
    print("xDistance: \(xDistance) | distance: \(distance)")
    self.lastPlayerPosition = player.position
}
```